# Wordpress - user_has_cap hook causes access denied on submit for review

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have got the following filter which should be removing editing capabilities for a certain user role on   for all posts except those which the user is the author of, and another specific custom post.

```
function allow_user_to_edit_cpt_filter( $capauser, $capask, $param){

if ( $user->roles[0] == 'aamrole_53e5009d7c32d' ) { 

        // code to get the id of the organisation post 
        $organisation_post = get_field('select_organisation', "user_$user_id") ;

        $user_posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, FROM wp_posts  WHERE post_author = " . $user_id , ARRAY_B );
        $allowed_posts = array();

        $user_posts = get_posts( $args );

        if( !empty($user_posts) ){
            foreach($user_posts as $post){
                $allowed_posts[] = $post->ID;
            }
        }
        $allowed_posts[] =  $organisation_post;

        //$allowed_posts = array(2376, 3091);
        $post = get_post( $param[2] );

        //If  post isn't allowed then remove edit capabilities on that post
        if( !in_array( $post->ID, $allowed_posts ) ){
            if( ( $param[0] == "edit_post" ) || ( $param[0] == "edit_published_posts" ) || ( $param[0] == "edit_others_posts" ) ) {
                foreach( (array)$capask as $capasuppr ) {
                   if ( array_key_exists($capasuppr, $capauser) ) {
                        $capauser[$capasuppr] = 0;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }  
  return $capauser;
}
add_filter('user_has_cap', 'allow_user_to_edit_cpt_filter', 100, 3 );
```

The problem with this code is that it then denies the user from submitting a post for review. I also  have the AAM(advanced access manager) installed, which I used to change the permissions on different user roles. Here is the list of the capabilities that are assigned to the role for which the code above is expected to execute.

- upload_files
- edit_posts
- edit_others_posts
- edit_published_posts
- read
- level 1
- level 0
- create_users
- list_users
- add_users

I would love to know why this filter is denying the user from submitting posts for review. To be precise, an `access denied` error is given during a request to `post.php`

Comment: Same issue, uploaded video https://youtu.be/PlKdOCFmyxo and added ticket on the AAM plugin forum. Hoping to get some answers. According to AAM the use has more than enough prive. WHen the post is saved or pubbed, the redirect is to post.php without an ID though, which is part of the issue surely.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might come across this, I am certainly not sure if this is the correct way, however I managed to do what I wanted.

Basically I added an if statement before removing capabilities

```
if ( (( 'publish' != $post->post_status ) || ( 'pending' != $post->post_status ) || ( 'auto-draft' != $post->post_status )) && ($post->post_author == $user_id) ) { 
     return $capauser;
}
```

This checks if the post is published pending or draft, and if it belongs to the user. If these conditions are true, then return the capabilities as they were.

The documentation has a very [similar example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap)